# rails: Issue with routes with second devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, routes

I tried to add a second model for "jobseeker",  I have an issue with routes when I try to go /jobseekers/sign_up, and when try another way it use devise/registrations/new view, which is not ok for me as I am not using the same fields.

I read and tried different ways but still not working.

I just want to use my jobseeker's controller as well as my jobseeker's custom view

I followed https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers to make it.

if you can tell me where the issue is, that would be very kind of you. Thanks.

For my routes I used:

```html
1)  devise_for :jobseekers, controllers: { sessions: "jobseekers/sessions", registrations: "jobseekers/registration" }

  ---> routes errors

2) devise_scope :jobseekers do
  get "sign_in", to: "jobseekers/sessions#new"
  get "sign_up", to: "jobseekers/registration#new"
end   --> routes routes
```

so generated new controllers:

```html
app/controllers/jobseekers/confirmations_controller.rb
app/controllers/jobseekers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
app/controllers/jobseekers/passwords_controller.rb
app/controllers/jobseekers/registrations_controller.rb
app/controllers/jobseekers/sessions_controller.rb
app/controllers/jobseekers/unlocks_controller.rb
```

And I also generated views as below

```html
app/views/jobseekers/confirmations/new.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/passwords/edit.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/passwords/new.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/registrations/edit.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/registrations/new.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/sessions/new.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/shared/_links.html.erb
app/views/jobseekers/unlocks/new.html.erb
```

Comment: Do you actually need to use Devise against multiple models, or would you be happier with Devise with your jobseeker class, including all necessary jobseeker fields?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Well I have company, tax info... which is useless for jobseeker, but it is just problem with routes, I am able to go to signin page with the custom view but iam not able to signup with my custom view, I tried different ways but it is still not working. thanks